# QTP doesnot run in another screen resolution, any suggestions?

Tags: screen, resolution, qtp

QTP which access an application object in test PC screen resolution doesnt access the application window object in laptop? any suggestions to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also do not understand the question, but it may well be a resolution problem: Try looking at the answer to [Mercury Quick Test Pro and Virtual machines: Works from one client machine but not another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91364/mercury-quick-test-pro-and-virtual-machines-works-from-one-client-machine-but-no).

Comment: this is the same issue which i am facing

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your code have many statements which involve coordinates?

If they involve coordinates then it is most likely that code will fail. If not post a code snippet here such that we can analyze it.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stackoverflow.
Just to let you know this should really be posted as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Don't really understand what you mean.
Just know at work we are using QTP and we don't really like it for many reasons...

You'd better give a try to Selenium it's a powerful tool :)

Answer (score -1):

hey if u are automating web application then change ur resolution to 100%. If its more or less than 100% then qtp scripts will fail.

```
                                   OR
```

An alternative solution, we can go for third party tool like Qres and MultiRes. These tools can be operated using QTP at runtime.
 So far I have not found a code for changing screen resolution at runtime using vb script. If anyone finds that, please post it.